# Usage of "noun of noun": mountain of an uncle, gem of a person

Tags: phrase-meaning, phrase-usage

*Mountain of an uncle*, *gem of a person*, *dude of an actor*, *dreamboat of a husband*. Please explain this usage of "noun of noun".

Answer (score 3):

From the OED (formatting mine):

> ***of*, preposition**
>
> **24.** Between two nouns in sense-apposition. **b.** in the sense "in the form of".
>   The leading noun is the latter, to which the preceding noun with *of* stands as a qualification, equivalent to an adjective; thus *that fool of a man* = "that foolish man, that man who deserves to be called 'fool'"; *that beast of a place* = "that beastly place".

---

Following that definition, if someone is described as *a gem of a person*, the leading noun in this expression is *person*, and *gem of* is equivalent to *beloved*; therefore, *a gem of a person* = "a beloved person, a person who deserves to be called 'gem'". The other expressions you listed follow the same pattern.

Answer (score 1):

1. **A mountain of an uncle** - most probably a rephrased version of "**a mountain of a man**" which means "**a very tall and strong guy**". When you say "**mountain of something**" you usually refer to that there is a large amount of something.
2. **A gem of a person** - refers to someone considered flawless, someone utterly precious and priceless.
3. **A dude of an actor** - refers to a very stylish and confident person *(an actor in this case)*.
4. **A dreamboat of a husband** - refers to a husband who seems very good or suitable, highly desirable, and very attractive.