# what's the meaning of "of" in "Whale of a squid"?

Tags: prepositions

"Whale of a Squid" is the second episode of Season One of PBS Kids' *Wild Kratts*. It was written and directed by Martin Kratt. I looked up both in Longman and OALD dictionaries, but still confusing about "of" mean. All the translation sites let me down.

In that video, the topic is about whales; in some clips, whales beat a squid.
IMO, "of" means "duel", but is it true, any examples?

Comment: This answers the question in the title: https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/140080/3395.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### It’s a big one

Luckily, there is a dictionary definition for **”whale of a”:**

> a large amount of something:
>
> - A whale of a lot of other people were there, too.
>
> If something is a whale of a thing, it is a very good thing:
>
> - Perry's done a whale of a job for us.
>
> — [*Cambridge Dictionary*](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/a-whale-of-a)

### It’s a metaphor

“Whale” is a **metaphor**<sup>([[Definition](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/metaphor)])</sup> for *a very large thing*, and “of” is being used this way:

> of <sup><sub>preposition</sub></sup> (**AMOUNT**)
>
> used after words or phrases expressing amount, number, or a particular unit:
>
> - a drop of rain
> - two pounds of potatoes
> - hundreds of people
>
> — [*Cambridge Dictionary*](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/of)

Comment: Good point! But in that video, the topic is about whales,  some clips about whales beat a squd. In this title, it might be other meaning.

Comment: @AladinLee - Oftentimes titles employ clever puns or plays on words. Because whales and squids are both sea creatures, the expression "Whale of a Squid" makes a clever title for the reasons explained in this answer. The word _of_ need not have any additional meaning related to the context of the video.

Comment: I agreed, it's kind of clever puns. I found many videos about whales using similar titles.